# BigQuery load job fails due to permission issues

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using the following [code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/python-client-migration#copying_a_table) to upload data from CSV file in Google Storage to BigQuery table:

```py
  from google.cloud import bigquery
  client = bigquery.Client()
  dataset_id = 'e'
  dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
  job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
  job_config.schema = [
      bigquery.SchemaField('itemcode', 'STRING'),
      bigquery.SchemaField('itemname', 'STRING'),
  ]
  job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1
  # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
  #job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
  uri = 'gs://e/2018-07-15/inventory.csv.gz'
  load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
      uri,
      dataset_ref.table('inventory'),
      job_config=job_config)  # API request

  assert load_job.job_type == 'load'

  load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.

  assert load_job.state == 'DONE'
  assert client.get_table(dataset_ref.table('inventory')).num_rows == 10
```

The Project is called BI it's ID is: BI-bi
I have a dataset called `e`  in this dataset I have a table called `inventory` with two columns `itemcode` and `itemname`.

For some reason this code fail with the following error:

```
> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST
> https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/USER/jobs: Access
> Denied: Dataset BI-bi:BI: The user USER@BI-bi.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset BI-bi:BI
```

When I'm going to the USER permissions I see that it has the following roles:

```
Big Query Job user
Storage Admin
```

The other options are:

[image]

I'm lost here. The docs doesn't explain what to do here.

error log:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "inventory.py", line 160,
> in <module>
>     job_config=job_config)  # API request   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py",
> line 689, in load_table_from_uri
>     job._begin(retry=retry)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py",
> line 397, in _begin
>     method='POST', path=path, data=self._build_resource())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py",
> line 271, in _call_api
>     return call()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
> line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
>     on_error=on_error,   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/api_core/retry.py",
> line 177, in retry_target
>     return target()   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/cloud/_http.py", line
> 293, in api_request
>     raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
> google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST
> https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/USER/jobs: Access
> Denied: Dataset BI-bi:BI: The user USER@BI-bi.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset BI-bi:BI
```

Comment: The error message talks about `BI-bi:BI`, not `BI-bi:e`. It's as if the dataset weren't specified properly - which I can see could cause a problem. Are you able to dump the load job request to see what it's doing?

Comment: The documentation for the specific library you're using should tell you how to enable request logging. I'm guessing this is the Python library? But is that error message *exactly* what's shown, and is the code *exactly* as shown as well? Or might that `BI`/`e` difference be due to not being the result of running that exact code?

Comment: @DaisyShipton see trace log in the updated question

Comment: That's a stack trace - I'm asking for a log of the HTTP request that was sent to BigQuery. It might also be instructive to print out `dataset_ref.table('inventory')`

Comment: You could dump `load_job` as well... that would be useful, if it shows the JSON that would be sent.

Comment: @DaisyShipton `print dataset_ref.table('inventory')` gives: `TableReference(u'BI-bi', 'e', 'inventory ')`

Comment: Right - that makes it very odd that it's complaining about `BI-bi:BI` as the dataset. I think we really need to see the job details. If you look in the console (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com) that should show you some of the details of the load job - could you have a look there, please?

Comment: @DaisyShipton I'll try to dump it.. but I'm why did it shows error for USER@BI-bi.iam.gserviceaccount.com     the USER isn't specified anywhere in my code. how did it choose it over the 20 other users available in the account?

Comment: It's using the default application credentials for your context. That could be via `gcloud auth login`, or setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, or the service account for the machine you're running on if this is running on GCE/GKE/AppEngine. But so long as the account has the right role, that should be fine.

Comment: @DaisyShipton could be scope related?  `SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write']`

Comment: @DaisyShipton I didn't find any where on the docs how to dump the log of the job.. all I get is the dump of the final exception

Comment: Okay, I would just look at the job in the console then. That will tell you the destination table it's trying to write to. If that shows as `BI-bi:BI.inventory`, that's the problem.

Comment: @DaisyShipton  What do you mean? I don't see that it tells me where it's going to write. I'm running it as a python script. The job isn't listed in the BigQuery UI

Comment: The BigQuery console, at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com, lists the jobs you've tried to run in "Job History". It includes the details of the job.

Comment: @DaisyShipton I don't see any of my job attempts there. The last record is from the 4th of July. I see there only jobs I tried to run from the UI itself.

Comment: That suggests you may be looking in the wrong project - you should be able to see all the jobs, as far as I'm aware. (It's possible that your user is restricted though - there's a lot that can be configured, of course.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton Intresting. Changing the code to : dataset_ref.table('e/inventory') gives: google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/BI-bi/jobs: Invalid table ID "e/inventory".

Comment: @DaisyShipton I have only one project in this account... But there are 6 datasets... before this step I'm doing the upload to google storage.. it works great. Only the big query makes problems

Comment: @DaisyShipton Could this be an issue with public vs non public dataset? My data set isn't listed under the public ones

Comment: @DaisyShipton It is permission issue. I gave my `USER` the  `BigQuery Admin` and the issue no longer appear. Now I get errors about my csv file :)  I'm not sure why I must give admin permissions to any job that just insert data. The error itself isn't clear. I'm not looking for creating table.. just uploading data to existed table.

Comment: I don't think you should need to just to append to an existing table. I'm still confused why it looks like it was talking about the wrong dataset though...

Comment: @DaisyShipton Sadly the docs are not that good. I'm having many problems with the initial support... BigQuery doesn't seems to be intuitive enough. On RedShift everything was easy and simple. I would expect the docs to explain how to dump the load.. but they don't. documentation is written for the people with the knowledge not for the first time users.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find this public [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#required_permissions) saying:

> When you are loading data into BigQuery from Cloud Storage, you must
>   be granted the bigquery.dataOwner or bigquery.dataEditor role at the
>   project level or at the dataset level.

And

> To load data from a Cloud Storage bucket, you must be granted
>   storage.objects.get permissions at the project level or on that
>   individual bucket.

This will help you to solve the permission issue while loading data from your bucket to BigQuery